# Images are not showing on blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, symlink

Why my images are not showing on blade file in live hosting even after performing the symlink, ps:-its working well on localhost

**PostController:**

```
 public function createpost(Request $request)
    {

       Post::create(
        [
            'user_id'=>$request->user_id,
            'post_title'=>$request->post_title,
            'post_body'=>$request->post_body,
            'post_image'=>$request->file('post_image')->store('public'),
            'status'=>1
       ]);
       echo "Recorded Successfully";
       echo "<a href='/post'>Click here</a> to go back";
     }
```

**Filesystems.php**

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],
```

**Blade.php file**

```
{{url('storage/'.$post->post_image) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `asset()` helper

```
{{ asset('storage/' . $post->post_image) }}
```

Or the `Storage` facade

```
{{ Storage::url($post->post_image) }}
```

Comment: It didnt worked brother! can you please go through the link and suggest whats wrong with it? Link:- https://www.jcisatashidham.com/blog

Comment: The image are well displayed

Comment: Thankyou for your concern sir! i had mistaken my URL